# Page reloads when I use the setState function in React.js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, web

When I use setState to change the object, the page reloads, resetting everything on the page. As I am making a tic-tac-toe app, either an X or 0 appears when I click on divs but when I use setState to change anything, the webpage resets, taking back everything to its initial position.

```
<script type="text/babel">
    function TicTacToe() {
        const [state, setState] = React.useState({
        turn: 0,
        player: 'player1'
        });
        
        function changePlayer() {
            if (state.player === 'player2') {
                setState({
                    ... state,
                    player: 'player1'
                })
            } else if (state.player === 'player1') {
                setState({
                    ... state,
                    player: 'player2'
                })
            }
        }

        function playerTurn() {
            if (state.turn % 2 === 0) {
                setState({
                    ... state,
                    player: 'player1'
                })
            } else {
                setState({
                        ... state,
                        player: 'player2'
                })
            }
        }

        function columnClicked(event) {
            let element = event.target;
            if (state.player === 'player2') {
                element.innerHTML= '<h1 class="symbols">0</h1>';
            } else if (state.player === 'player1') {
                element.innerHTML= '<h1 class="symbols">X</h1>';
            }
        }

        return (
            <div>
                <Heading />
                <div className='container'>
                    <CreateRow />
                    <CreateRow />
                    <CreateRow />
                </div>
                <button onClick={ changePlayer }>Change Player</button>
            </div>
        );
    }

    ReactDOM.render(<TicTacToe />, document.getElementById('tic_tac_toe'));
</script>
```

Comment: ... state  should not have a whitespace, ...state

Comment: [Here's a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yLphgm8b/) for this question, the state appears to work fine. If you can provide a JS fiddle that reproduces this problem, we can better assist you.

Comment: is your `tic_tac_toe` div inside a form for some reason? If so, this button will submit the form and reload the page. If that is the problem, add `type="button"` to the button.

Answer (score 1):

Prevent a browser reload/refresh by using `event.preventDefault()` as follows.

```
        function changePlayer(event) {

            event.preventDefault()

            if (state.player === 'player2') {
                setState({
                    ... state,
                    player: 'player1'
                })
            } else if (state.player === 'player1') {
                setState({
                    ... state,
                    player: 'player2'
                })
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two different things and two different approaches:

If you want to stop unnecessary re-render:

```
shouldComponentUpdate() {
    return false; // This will cause component to never re-render.
  }
```

If you want to stop unnecessary refresh on `setState` :

```
demoFunction(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({sample: true});
  }
```